# Удалить все нули кроме "10"

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Задача: удалить из результата с дробными числами **все нули, кроме цифры "10"**, ее нужно передать как есть.
Удалось организовать удаление нулей после точки, вместе с самой точкой (так и должно быть):

```
$diametr_result = "2 2.50 2.0 10";
echo $diametr_result = preg_replace('/\.0+/', '', $diametr_result);
```

Но как достичь желаемого результата, не могу понять..

Comment: найти `'/(\.[^0]+)0+|\.0+/'` заменить на `'$1'`

Comment: *удалить ... все нули, кроме цифры "10"* 100=>0? 1.10=>1.? 101=>1? *кроме цифры "10"* Это число...

Comment: @Akina, немного не поняли задачу. Только дробные числа и удалить нули с точкой. 2.50 => 25, 1.10 => 11. Вот же

Comment: @Lexx918 спасибо, то что нужно! Если оформите ответом, отмечу как решение

Comment: @Lexx918 все таки нет, случаются неточные вычисления. Например при значениях "3.75 4.5 5.00", после 5 остается точка..

Comment: Что если загнать в массив при помощи explode с разделением по пробелам, потом в цикле округлить все какой-то стандартной функцией, попутно собирая обратно в строку?

Comment: @Vadim ну каким будет конкретное решение, предложенное вами? я не совсем понял, как это должно выглядеть

Comment: @Lexx918 вот такое решение является подходящим '/(\.[^0])0+|\.0+/' , почти тоже что предложили вы. Будете оформлять ответ? Если нет, то сам это сделаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, следующее решение является в этом случае наиболее подходящим:

```
$diametr_result = "2 2.50 2.0 3.75 4.5 5.00";
echo $diametr_result = preg_replace('/(\.[^0])0+|\.0+/', '$1', $diametr_result);
```

удаляет нули у дробных чисел.
(почти то что предложил @Lexx918, но т.к оформить свой комментарий ответом он не пожелал, делаю это сам)

Answer (score 1):

```
  $diametr_result = "2 2.50 2.0 10";
  $a = explode(" ", $diametr_result);
  $test = '';
  foreach($a as $e) {
  $test .= (float)$e.' ';
  }
  echo trim($test);
```